# i want to create a new droppable when my mouse hover a droppable

Tags: jquery, droppable

this is my demo, i just want when i drag the draggable div hover a droppable div ,there will be another div created and with droppable and so on，during this time press and hold the mouse

it works sometimes but mostly not,please help me check this thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <style>
        .drag { float: left;width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; }
        .drop { float: left;margin: 10px; width: 60px; height: 60px; background: #999; color: #fff; padding: 10px; }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i=0;

            $( ".drag" ).draggable();
            $( ".drop" ).droppable({
                drop: drop,
                over: zhuce
            }); 

            function drop(){
                alert("drop"+$(this).html());
            }

            function zhuce( event, ui ) {
                console.log("now fly over-->"+$(this).html());
                newDIV();
            }

            function out( event, ui ) {
                console.log("out-->"+$(this).html());
            }

            function newDIV(){
                i++;
                var a = $("<div>",{class:"drop",html:i});
                $("body").append(a);
                var list = $(".drop");
                list.each(function(x,node){
                    $(node).droppable({
                        tolerance: 'intersect',
                        over: zhuce,
                        drop: drop          
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="drag">Drag me</div>
    <div class="drop">Drop here</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Draggable` doesn't update `droppable` info by default, so when you add new ones they are not taken into account by item being dragged. If you drag the mouse out of the screen it seems to refresh calculations somehow, so I guess that's why sometimess it works sometimes not. 
But there's a way to systematize `droppable` calculations, it's the option called `refreshPositions`. If you set it to true, then it'll calculate `droppable` position on `mousemove`, and your code will work correctly. See:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var i=0;

            $( ".drag" ).draggable(
                {
                    refreshPositions: true
                });
            $( ".drop" ).droppable({
                drop: drop,
                over: zhuce
            }); 

            function drop(){
                alert("drop"+$(this).html());
            }

            function zhuce( event, ui ) {
                
                console.log("now fly over-->"+$(this).html(), $(this).draggable('instance'));
                newDIV();
            }

            function out( event, ui ) {
                console.log("out-->"+$(this).html());
            }

            function newDIV(){
                i++;
                var a = $("<div>",{class:"drop",html:i});
                $("body").append(a);
                
                var list = $(".drop");
                list.each(function(x,node){
                    
                    $(node).droppable({
                        tolerance: 'intersect',
                        over: zhuce,
                        drop: drop          
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

```css
 .drag { float: left;width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; }
        .drop { float: left;margin: 10px; width: 60px; height: 60px; background: #999; color: #fff; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="drag">Drag me</div>
    <div class="drop">Drop here</div>
```

Comment: yeah ，it works! i do all my work on the droppable,not pay attention on the draggable,
 thank you very much!